# Как правильно создать объект

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Суть**: Пользователь на сайте в форме заполняет данные, примерно такой вид данных на выходе - idUser, date1, date2 (причем он может внести несколько строк, с разными датами но idUser будет одинаковый соответственно).

**Вопрос**: Подскажите как мне создать объект и в цикле его наполнять этими данными, примерно как с массивом с помощью push ? (Хотелось бы, в дальнейшем из этого объекта вытягивать данные только по idUser например с помощью $.map)

**Update**: Хочу примерно такую структуру:
var Data = { id : { n: [] } } - объект создаем

после заполнения данными:

```
var Data = {
  id1 : { 1:[ date1, date2 ], 2:[ date1, date2 ] },
  id2 : { 1:[ date1, date2 ], 2:[ date1, date2 ], 3:[ date1, date2 ] }
....  
}
```

Comment: Какие возникают сложности то? Объект в котором ключи - idUser, а значение - массив с датами ...

Comment: @MedvedevDev, примерно так: var Object = {  id: [ ]  } ?

Comment: Если я правильно понял вопрос, то да. Но конечно же не используйте `Object` как имя этого объекта.

Comment: @MedvedevDev, у меня трудность в наполнении этого объекта данными. Вот к примеру у меня есть 2 строки(id,date1,date2): 1) 12, 01.01.2000, 02.02.2000 2) 12, 01.02.2001, 02.02.2001. Как записать это правильно в объект?

Comment: 1) `id` он на то и id, что должен быть уникальным (в вашем случае и там и там 12); 2) так и записывайте `{ 12: [ '01.01.2000', '02.02.2000' ], 13: [ '01.02.2001', '02.02.2001' ] }`; 3) Лучше переводить даты в UNIX (хотя тут от использования наверное больше зависит).

Comment: @MedvedevDev, спасибо за ваш ответ. Поразмыслил и понял что не верно истолковал итоговую картину. Посмотрите по возможности правку в вопрос. У меня под одни ид может быть несколько пар дат. И самое главное как ключу присвоить имя в объекте? (на рисунке id1 но мне надо чтобы был например 12345, data['имя'] не помогает мне почему то)

Answer (score 0):

думаю вам подойдет следующая структура :

```
{
  "1": [
    {
      "date1": "12.02.2017",
      "date2": "12.022015"
    },
    {
      "date1": "12.04.2017",
      "date2": "12.05.2015"
    }
  ],
  "2": [
    {
      "date1": "11.04.2017",
      "date2": "01.05.2015"
    }
  ]
}
```

Где обьект местит в себе свойства, которые равны вашим `id`, а уже ети свойства являються массивами обьектов, хранящих даты, вот пример реализации :

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', doIt);

var someObj = {};

function doIt() {
  document.querySelector('#add').addEventListener('click', function() {
    var id = document.querySelector('[name="id"]').value;
    var _date1 = document.querySelector('[name="date1"]').value;
    var _date2 = document.querySelector('[name="date2"]').value;

    // если свойство обьекта someObj с именем id не существует
    // создаем его и присваеваем ему пустой массив
    if (someObj[id] === undefined) {
      someObj[id] = [];
    }

    // тут пробегаем по массиву, смотрим есть ли уже такой елемент
    // если есть то не добавляем (эт от себя добавил)
    var add = true;
    if (someObj[id].length > 0) {
      someObj[id].forEach(function(e) {
        if (e.date1 == _date1 && e.date2 == _date2) {
          add = false;
        }
      });
    }

    // пушим наши даты в наш ид 
    if (add)
      someObj[id].push({
        date1: _date1,
        date2: _date2
      });

  });

  document.querySelector('#print').addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log(someObj);
  });
};
```

```html
ID:<input name="id" /><br/> Date:
<input name="date1" /><br/> Date2:
<input name="date2" /><br/>
<button id="add">add to object</button><br/>
<button id="print">print object in console</button>
<br/>
<div id="data"></div>
```